# ArangoDB: Last of collection in path

Tags: arangodb

I have a couple of document collections containing assets and asset types and an edge collection for creating:

- hierarchy of assets types (*dmr-radio* `is_a` radio `is_a` *asset*)
- hierarchy of the contents of assets (*the vehicle* `contains` *the radio*)
- links to what type of asset an asset is (*the vehicle* `is_a` *vehicle*, *the radio* `is_a` *dmr-radio*).

[image]

I am trying to find all radios that are in a vehicle. I was thinking of using a [k Paths](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-k-paths.html) graph query to get all the assets that are a type of radio (see below), but I am struggling to find a way to then return only the asset that is the radio (the last vertex that is in the *assets* collection).

Is there a way to get the last vertex in a path from a certain collection and is there a better way to do this query?

```
FOR path
  IN 1..100 OUTBOUND K_PATHS
  'assets/493761' TO 'assetTypes/radio'
  GRAPH assetRelationships
  RETURN path
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to obtain what I wanted using a [User-defined Function](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/extending.html)

```js
/**
 * ArangoDB User-defined Function for getting the last
 * vertex of a collection type in a graph path
 *
 * @param {Path} path ArangoDB graph path to search
 * @param {string} type Name of collection that the returned
 *   vertex should be from
 */
const lastOf = (path, type) => {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  type += '/';
  
  for (let i = path.vertices.length - 1; i => 0; i--) {
    if (path.vertices[i]._id.startsWith(type)) {
      return path.vertices[i];
    }
  }

  return null;
};
```

which I am registering when I set up my database connection

```js
import { Database } from 'arangojs';

const database = new Database({
 ...
});

...

await database.createFunction('MY_FUNC::LAST_OF', lastOf.toString(), true);
```

and am then using in a AQL query

```
FOR path
  IN 1..100 OUTBOUND K_PATHS
  'assets/493761' TO 'assetTypes/radio'
  GRAPH assetRelationships
  RETURN MY_FUNC::LAST_OF(path, 'assets')
```